# Repo.insert returning preloaded associations?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, repo

```
Repo.insert(changeset)
```

returns `{:ok, struct}`, but struct has no preloaded associations.
Am I forced to select query to preload it's associations? Or can I avoid a useless query somehow?

Comment: You are going to have to call `Repo.preload/3` yourself.

Comment: |> Repo.insert
|> Repo.preload(:posts) like this?

Comment: Yup, like that. BUT, you just inserted the recorded, it is most likely there is nothing to preload. :) So you can also explicitly set the field to an empty list, if you want to.

Comment: If you use `Repo.insert!`, yes. If you just use `Repo.insert`, you are going to have to unwrap the tuple first. @JoséValim, It could `belong_to` another record, so it is possible there is something to preload.

Comment: or a `cast_assoc`

Comment: @ryanwinchester `cast_assoc` would only cast a related record but not preload it when inserting.

Comment: @ashraf no i was replying to José and Justin. There would be something to preload even if it wasn't `belongs_to`, if you were using `cast_assoc` on it

Comment: @ryanwinchester apologies mate, yeah, in this case you're right :)